# utf-8 files changed to windows-1252 when ftp'd to server

Tags: apache, jsp, character-encoding, markdown, jekyll

**UPDATE:**
New development! Changing the file extension to JSP before uploading to the server (which is JSP based Apache) changes the encoding of the page to the specified UTF-8!

Sadly this doesn't really help as I would need to manually change all the file extensions every time I want to upload changes to the servers. Based on this most recent info, any ideas? Bueller?

---

I built a site on Jekyll. When I *jekyll serve* it looks great on my localhost. `document.charset` is `"UTF-8"`. Perf.

Problem comes when I upload it to our server (www.example.com/static/minisite/). Special characters don't display correctly (e.g. 'whatâ€™s next') & when I `document.charset` it says `"Windows-1252"`. This is breaking all the ' and " that Markdown will automatically convert to fancy quotes.

Everything else (i.e. www.example.com/sales) on that server is "UTF-8".

Troubleshooting steps I've taken:

- Verified that all pages have `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
- Added `encoding: "utf-8"` to _config.yml
- Checked encoding on all .md files on /src & .html files on /deploy using 
  `file -I *.md` & `file -I *.html`. Results are what you would expect: `about.md:        text/plain; charset=utf-8`
- Tried adding a .htaccess file to the directory with many variations of this: `adddefaultCharset UTF-8`. I think this used to work and solved the problem briefly. Now it gives me 404 errors on every folder I put it in
- Changed my FTP settings to `Force UTF-8`
- I tried uploading the index.html file that locally is UTF-8 to a different server (a Drupal site I manage) and `document.charset` says `Windows-1252`
- I tried bulk changing encodings of every file on both src and deploy folders using `find -E . -regex '.*\.(html|md|htm)' -exec iconv [-f windows-1252] [-t utf-8] -o {} {} \;`
- Response Headers: Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

I am a bit exasperated at this point. I can't tell what is, when they are, and where they are changing encoding. Because Markdown decides it knows best and will change any ' to a fancy ’, I am almost to the point of ditching Jekyll altogether since this issue only occurs on this one Jekyll microsite that I have on that server.

Comment: What encoding is reported in the HTTP headers returned by the server?

Comment: @Waylan Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1. Also added to post

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the FTP upload, try setting the FTP Transfer mode to BINARY before uploading your files, that way the FTP Server should not modify your text files at all.